# Selenium Webdriver How to get locations during drag and drop for debugging

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck with this scenario where I have to drag and drop a share point Webpart on the page. I am using IE 11 and C# Webdriver. I have tested my drag and drop code on Jquery UI page and seems to work perfectly. However in my real scenario after I get the source and target web elements and perform the drag and drop, nothing seems to happen. I have tried to use the mouse API events also to simulate drag and drop but nothing seems to work. Is there any way of testing at which location the drag and drop is being performed. The mouse does not actually move to the location so I have no idea of identifying where the drag and drop is being performed? To me it seems that the drag and drop location are not correct but I can't be sure as the mouse does not move to those locations.